# Add data in Json and Merge two json file in C#

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net, key-value

I have two json format data

```
"@xmlns": "TestValue",
"Complete": {
  "Heights": {
    "Height": {
      "Person": {
        "PersonName": [ {
          "@Name": "Mrx",
          "Attributes": {
            "Attribute": ["Tall", "Small", "Fair", "Intelligente", "Clever", "OnTime" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Like this there is other Mry with attributes.

This json belong to all person in society and there is another person json which is subset of same json but it's store in different file.

There are two json files: `allPerson.json` and `apecialPerson.json`.

I have to perform two operation here:

1. I have add HasPass="N" value in `allPerson.json` and HasPass="Y" in `specialPerson.json`

so json should like this for `allPerson.json`

```
"@xmlns": "TestValue",
"Complete": {
  "Heights": {
    "Height": {
      "Person": {
        "PersonName": [ {
          "@Name": "Mrx",
          "Attributes": {
            "Attribute": [ "Tall" HasPass="N", "Small" HasPass="N", "Fair" HasPass="N", "Intelligente" HasPass="N", "Clever" HasPass="N", "OnTime" HasPass="N"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and for `specialPerson.json` HasPass="Y" on value level.

2. After this I have to merge all two json to create one merge json file `merge.json` where It will take the value from `allperson.json` and `specialPerson.json`

If there is common data for both file it will take those value whose has HasPass="Y"

MergeJson will look like this

```
"@xmlns": "TestValue",
"Complete": {
  "Heights": {
    "Height": {
      "Person": {
        "PersonName": [{
          "@Name": "Mrx",
          "Attributes": {
            "Attribute": [ "Tall" HasPass="Y", "Small" HasPass="N", "Fair" HasPass="Y", "Intelligente" HasPass="N", "Clever" HasPass="Y", "OnTime" HasPass="N" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried to format you question to understand it better, but still `Attribute` array seems malformed JSON. Please make sure to update you question to reflect how `Attribute` should look like. And how to merge if `Tall` for example has both HasPass="Y" and HasPass="N"?

Comment: first need to HasPass="N" for all attribute value in allPerson.json and HasPass="Y" for all attribute in specialPerson.json and after that need to merge both the file.e.g. if Mrx is present in both the file and has Tall attribute then take HasPass="Y" in merge file and other attribute value will be hasPass="N". Hope I'm clear this time.

Comment: Please provide valid example of expected json for `Tall` attribute after merge when it has both `HasPass="Y"` and `HasPass="N"`

Comment: What I am trying to say is, first of all, that `"Attribute": [ "Tall" HasPass="Y" ]` is not valid `JSON` and, second of all, how should `"Attribute": [ "Tall" HasPass="Y" HasPass="N" ]` look like after merge?

Comment: It should be like "Attribute": [ "Tall":{ HasPass="Y"} ] and after merge also it should come like this only "Attribute": [ "Tall":{ HasPass="Y"} ] based on condition if Tall is common for both Json

Comment: Alright, makes, sense. What have you already tried? Have you tried to deserialize it with `Json.NET` and iterate through items, find same names and merge? Where did you stuck?

Comment: First I need to add hasPass="Y" or hasPass="N" in existing json file. Here I'm struggling to add this value in existing json and same case for merging as i'm new for Json and please excuse me for all confusion.

Comment: No worries, it makes sense now. Please post the code how you are trying to do it.

Comment: string json = File.ReadAllText("allPerson.json");
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); after that I have to loop through to go to attribute and hasPass="N" and for this I have to convert Tall as key.I'm struggling to do this.

Comment: Sounds right. I suggest you to define a model to deserialize json to instead of dynamic. Tall should not be a string, but object. Try to define a model and I will help you more. It will be more clear for yourself.

Comment: Are you sure your json examples represent correct structure. It does not work very well to me when I try to implement solution. Make sure arrays and objects specified correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
class PersonName
{
    [JProperty("@Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

class Attributes
{
    public List<Dictionalry<string, AttributeHassPass>> Attribute { get; set; }
}

class AttributeHassPass
{
    public string HassPass { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize first file you will get something like:

```
persons ... probably list initialized like:

{
    new Person()
    {
        PersonName = new PersonName()
        {
            Name = "Mrx",
            Attributes = new Attributes()
            {
                Attribute = new List<Dictionalry<string, AttributeHassPass>>()
                {
                    new Dictionalry<string, AttributeHassPass>()
                    {
                        { "Tall", null }
                    }
                    new Dictionalry<string, AttributeHassPass>()
                    {
                        { "Small", null }
                    }
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`personName` in real example will be property of a person and so on up the structure.

When you will iterate through persons you can now update its attributes:

```
foreach (var dictionary in personName.Attributes.Attribute)
{
    foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
    {
        kvp.Value = new AttributeHassPass()
        {
            HassPass = "N"
        }
    }
}
```

Same you can to for second file.

Then when you need to merge best approach would be first to create dictionary from persons from second file for easier lookup:

```
// Find out how to get it better or from where.
IDictionary<string, Attributes> lookup = persons2.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Attributes);
```

And the you merge. Iterate through persons from first file and lookup person fron secong to see if there is attribute to merge:

```
foreach (var person in persons1)
{
    // Get name of a person from first file.
    var name = person.PersonName.Name;

    // Lookup the name from second file.
    Attributes attributes;
    if (lookup.TryGetValue(name, out attributes))
    {
        // We found value to merge.
        foreach (var dictionary in person.PersonName.Attributes.Attribute)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
            {
                var matchingAttribute = attributes.Attribute.Select(dict => dict.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)).SingleOrDefault();
                if (matchingAttribute != null)
                {
                    // It means we have found an attrubite to merge.
                    kvp.HassPass = matchingAttribute.First().HassPass;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After all that persons from first file will have merged attributes from second file.

I understand it is messy, but I cannot do better example without knowing exact json structure. The one you provided in the question is not completely corrent. But I hope you now have some idea how to meve on.

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer.I had model class where my Attributes class was List<string> for allPerson.json and when I have changed model class of Attributes  from List to Dictionary. After that I'm calling DeserializeObject method for desialization and getting error for conversion from List<string>  to dictionary and because of change in model class breaking the existing code. I have to  desialization  for adding hasPass.

Comment: My example won't work 100% it's just to give you an idea. It is hard to provide better solution without having you json files and seeing structure. But I think you can either provide file for reference or  try to think how to deserialize it correctly.